# module 'guestbook.views' has no attribute 'index'

Tags: django

i make a startapp "guestbook" inside my django project.

here is the file list(guestbook)

```
__init__.py  admin.py  apps.py  migrations  models.py  template  tests.py  urls.py  views.py
```

guestbook/template

```
guestbook
```

guestbook/template/guestbook

```
index.html
```

i want to get the index render but i am facing error which is

```
 File "C:\Users\_monster\Desktop\skill\django_frontend\backend\f_django\guestbook\urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    path('', views.index, name='index')
AttributeError: module 'guestbook.views' has no attribute 'index'
```

here is my file setting
main urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    # main url, folder url
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('hello/', include('hello.urls')),
    path('guestbook/', include('guestbook.urls'))

]
```

guestbook/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

# import everything from views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

guestbook/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'guestbook/index.html')
```

so what is problem here ? the index.html are inside the folder

Comment: The code you have posted looks ok. The error suggests that `guestbook/views.py` does not contain an `index` method, but you have shown one in your question. Perhaps you have not saved your files or restarted the server after making changes. Or perhaps you have added the `index` method to the wrong file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I Tried almost everything to solve the issue but couldnt.
I just changed the name of function index from views.py to index2(guestbook/views.py)in your case!! Then i replicated those changes to (guestbook/urls.py) as

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index2, name='index')
]
```

It happened miraculously. And the console showed no errors anymore!! When i switched back again to whatever previously was, (that is to index from from index2) everything was running correctly